# How many 8 letter words are there using the letters X, Y, Z containing at least one X and two Ys?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Not sure how to approach this question. I have $3^8$ total possible words, but obviously some of these don't meet the requirements. So now I want to figure out how many of these don't meet the requirements and subtract that from the total number. If anyone could give some indication on how I can get this number I would greatly appreciate it.

METHOD FOR ANSWERING:

1. Find the total number of possible words. Which is $3^8$
2. Use the inclusion-exclusion principle with the 0X, 0Y and 1Y. These are all ways in which the words created won't satisfy the mentioned restrictions in the question. $|0X|$=$|0Y|$=$2^8$. Since we have 2 remaining choices for the 8 remaining slots. $|1Y|$ = $8*2^7$ Since there's 7 slots to be filled with Xs and Zs and the Y could be in any of the 8 slots so multiply by 8 to ensure all possibilities are counted. Then consider the intersection of 2 elements. The ones with 0Y and 1Y you don't have to calculate since it's an impossible scenario. However when we have 0X and 0Y we know there is only one possibility remaining when they're all Zs.
3. Once you've calculated everything you can simply subtract the value you just calculated away from the total value leaving you with your answer.

Comment: I did a similar kind of question a few days ago using the inclusion exclusion principle. It had 3 variables like this one and each one only had to appear one time, unlike this one where each element has to appear at least once or twice. I'm not sure how to adapt the inclusion-exclusion principle in order to make it so that I can make it include something twice.

Comment: There are two ways in which your word could fail to have at least two $Y's$.  Either it has no $Y's$ at all or it has exactly $1$.

Comment: You cannot have: $1) \ $ Just one $Y,\  2)$ No $Y$'s,$\  3)$ No $X$'s

Comment: Okay thank you both for the input. I'm going to try and finish off this question. & see whether I get the answer right using my current understanding. thank you a lot

Comment: Cool, no problem.

Comment: Okay so I've set my answer out as follows. So I have $|0X \cup 1Y \cup 0Y| = |0X| + |1Y| + |0Y| - |0X \cap 1Y| - |0X \cap 0Y| - |1Y \cap 0Y| + |0X \cap 1Y \cap 0Y|$
So now from here I just need to calculate. For $|0X|$ is the total number of possible ways I can have this just $2^8$ whereas for example $|1Y|$ would be $2^7*8$ multiplying by 8 for the total number of positions the 1Y could reside in. I know the ones with intersect including 0Y and 1Y aren't possible so they all come to 0. Leaving $|1Y \cap 0X|$ & $|0Y \cap 0X|$ now for this would it simply be 1 when I have 0X and 0Y and 8 for1Y

Comment: Hi Adam, I did make an edit above. Would $|1Y \cap 0X|$ just be 8 ?

Comment: Yes. Also I was wrong in my last comment, |$0Y \cap 0X| \neq \emptyset $. What element is in both?

Comment: There is one way to have no x's and no y's, namely all z's.  There are eight ways to have one y and no x's.  ($8$ positions for the y, and the rest z's).

Comment: Yes I was going to let IKnowNothing figure that out. Although he can't possibly know that as his name suggests...

Comment: I did write 1 down on the sheet of paper I have in front of me. So I guess I did know that at least haha. Thank you for all the help once again

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3908342/edit) your question to include your work, rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: I'll make sure to change the original post to include the solution after I've finished writing it down on the paper and checking it gives me the correct answer. Just want to make it 100% certain before I start writing anything

Comment: Also, feel free to write an answer to your own question, which is encouraged on this site. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.